# Redirection in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a simple virtual host to emulate a few specific responses that, in production, will come from a single URL. By way of an example, the production URL might look like this:

```
http://domain.com/getdeviceinfo/info.bin
```

It actually returns text in `.ini` format. I've set up several test files in my webroot at `/info/(legacy|new)/(daily|monthly)/device.htm` that will test several different responses and I'd like to set up redirection so that I can redirect the same-ish url to the appropriate resource. The test URL might look something like this:

```
http://devdomain.com/devicename/legacy/monthly/getdeviceinfo/info.bin
```

What I'd like to do is extract the appropriate values and serve up (in this example)

```
/info/legacy/monthly/devicename.htm
```

What Chrome, at least, is doing instead is attempting to download something called `info.bin`.

Here's my `location` block:

```
location ~ ^/(?<device>[^/]+)/(?<software>[^/]+)/(?<plan>[^/]+)/getdeviceinfo/info.bin$ {
  alias /opt/dev/hughesnet-modem-simulator/info/$software/$plan;
  try_files $uri $uri $device.htm
}
```

I've also tried setting the `alias` value to `/opt/dev/hughesnet-modem-simulator/info/$software/$device.htm` in lieu of `try_files`. I know I've just borked up the syntax, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

My current `location` block:

```
location ~ ^/(?<device>[^/]+)/(?<software>[^/]+)/(?<plan>[^/]+)/getdeviceinfo/info.bin$ {
  types {}
  default_type text/plain;
  alias /opt/dev/project-root/info/$software/$plan/$device.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bin` is mapped by default to the MIME type `application/octet-stream`, which is why the browser tries to download it.

To fix this, override the MIME type mapping within your `location` block:

```
location /.... {
    types { }
    default_type text/plain;
    # the rest of your stuff
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in the last day or so, this has stopped working for me. Clearly I've done something, but I don't know what it was. Now, though, a file named `info.bin` is being downloaded (unexpected) and its content is that of `$device.htm` (expected). I've updated my question with the location block. Do you see anything that I borked up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing alias-with-variables with try_files is probably the cause of your issue.  Instead of using alias, just use root:

```
# Including the /s in the variables makes the try_files a little more efficient
location ~ ^(?<device>/[^/]+)(?<software>/[^/]+)(?<plan>/[^/]+)/getdeviceinfo/info.bin$ {
  # Set the root to the base of all the files
  root /opt/dev/hughesnet-modem-simulator/info;

  # construct the file path to append to the root
  try_files $software$plan$device.htm =404;
}
```